# Can the electric field of an EM wave have a component in the direction of the wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electric-fields, electrical-engineering

I am currently taking a course in electromagnetics and i've stumbled into a problem.

On the Engineering electromagnetics book by sadiku there is a question with the electric field of plane wave as follows:

$$E = (10a_y + 5a_z)\cos(\omega*t +2y-4z)\rm V/m.$$

But on another book I've read, a wave cannot have electric field components along its directions of propagation.

[image: q]

In the above electric field, the wave is moving in the $yz$ plane i.e. it has a direction in $y$ and in $z$. The electric field directions are in $y$ and $z$. Does this violate the condition from the book or is there a different interpretation to this.

Comment: see any non-TEM waveguide field, e.g., TE or TM modes in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_mode#Waveguide_modes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the given electric field $$\vec E=(10 \hat{\mathbf a}_y + 5 \hat{\mathbf a}_z) \cos (\omega t + 2y - 4z ) \rm{\ V/m},$$
what is the propagation vector $\vec k$ in ($\vec k\cdot \vec r$) ?

With that $\vec k$, what is the value of $\vec k \cdot \vec E$?

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten that two vectors in a plane can be orthogonal too.